# Add libc support to use libintl.h header in android ndk

Tags: c, android-ndk

I am new in Android NDK and i want to use the header of `#include<libintl.h>`, But the error that in compile time i faced it is `error: libintl.h : No such file or directory`. I know that libc has been supported in android ndk caused by [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html#tools). But, i don't know how to include and use it ? :-/  So, how can i use this header file in android ?

My simplest code is as follows :

```
#include <libintl.h>

void main()
{
}
```

Android.mk:

```
#
# Compile axel
# 
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mylib.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H $(cflags_loglevels)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Log Error:

```
/home/hossein/workspace/Project/jni/mylib.h: error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong ? How can i include `libintl.h`?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

The functionality in libintl.h is indeed included with glibc, but it is not included in Android's stripped-down libc.  You'll have to build a standalone copy of libintl yourself.